# does it matter if bad sites link to your site

Tags: seo

it maybe be common knowledge, but there seems to some recent changes so i want to get it cleared up. Does it matter if a site that is blacklisted by search engines link to your site Or even just a site that has come to be known the spam hub.

I know quality of link affects positively but can it affect negatively

Answer (score 1):

If a site is blacklisted by Google the odds are it is considered a bad site. I wouldn't think links from those sites carry any positive weight and would be considered a bad link.

You can [disavow links from bad sites in your Google Webmaster Tools account](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2648487?hl=en). So if you have a bad link pointing to your site from a banned site, you can disavow it there.

Comment: i also read that since google search engine update named 'penguin' bad back links affect negatively.